# Could not write TTD trace -- has synchronous module loading completed? nodejs debugging node chakkara

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am trying **NodeChakra Time Travel Debug** extension for reverse execution debugging. For this,

1) I installed this extension **VSCode**.

2) Add launch configuration -> Add Configuration -> Time Travel Node Launch -> Set program file to start

Here is the configuration look like

```
{
   "type": "node",
   "request": "launch",
   "name": "Launch Program",
   "program": "${workspaceFolder}/demo.js"
}
```

Step over works but when I try to Step Back it shows the error

```
TTD: Failed to launch time-travel debugging session -- "Could not write TTD trace -- has synchronous module loading completed?"
```

Here is the code that I am checking

```
console.log("hi");
var array = [1, 2, 3]
for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    console.log(array[index]);

}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Copy and paste from a similar question asked on the github repo [here](https://github.com/mrkmarron/node-chakracore-time-travel-debugger/issues/5).

The Node.js loading process is a bit complicated and, as a result, the TTD process does not record the execution of the synchronous module loading activity (basically anything before the event loop starts to dispatch) so the time-travel debugger cannot replay this part of the application.

I took the code from the stackoverflow post and just wrapped it in a setImmediate so it executes after the synchronous loads:

```
setImmediate(() => {
    console.log("hi");
    var array = [1, 2, 3]
    for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
        console.log(array[index]);
    }
});
```

Now setting a breakpoint at the array assignment etc. and stepping back should work fine.